# How to advoid Unknown field: MyJSON.number

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, parser

I am having trouble with deserialising a jsonstring. In my debug I get the error System.JSONException: Unknown field: MyJSON.number. As number is a reserved field in salesforce I replace it with numberRep. I dont get why I get this error.

webservice

```
  @HttpPost
     global static void createOpportunity() {
      RestRequest req = RestContext.request;  
         string a = req.requestBody.toString().remove('\\');
         system.debug('DEB1: '+ a);         
          MyJSON tClass = MyJSON.parse(a);
         system.debug('DEB2: '+ tClass);
         system.debug('DEB3: '+ tClass.billing.address_1 );
         system.debug('DEB4: '+ tClass.cart_hash);
    }
```

Class

```
public class MyJSON{
    public Integer id;  //160
    public Integer parent_id;   //0
    public String numberRep;    //160
    public String order_key;    //wc_order_mGsqFiG3RfTGz
    public String created_via;  //admin
    public String version;  //3.5.7
    public String status;   //pending
    public String currencyRep;  //EUR
    public String date_created; //2019-03-22T07:29:08
    public String date_created_gmt; //2019-03-22T07:29:08
    public String date_modified;    //2019-03-22T07:29:14
    public String date_modified_gmt;    //2019-03-22T07:29:14
    public String discount_total;   //0.00
    public String discount_tax; //0.00
    public String shipping_total;   //0.00
    public String shipping_tax; //0.00
    public String cart_tax; //0.00
    public String total;    //0.00
    public String total_tax;    //0.00
    public boolean prices_include_tax;
    public Integer customer_id; //0
    public String customer_ip_address;  //
    public String customer_user_agent;  //
    public String customer_note;    //
    public cls_billing billing;
    public cls_shipping shipping;
    public String payment_method;   //
    public String payment_method_title; //
    public String transaction_id;   //
    public cls_date_paid date_paid;
    public cls_date_paid_gmt date_paid_gmt;
    public cls_date_completed date_completed;
    public cls_date_completed_gmt date_completed_gmt;
    public String cart_hash;    //
    public cls_meta_data[] meta_data;
    public cls_line_items[] line_items;
    public cls_tax_lines[] tax_lines;
    public cls_shipping_lines[] shipping_lines;
    public cls_fee_lines[] fee_lines;
    public cls_coupon_lines[] coupon_lines;
    public cls_refunds[] refunds;
    public class cls_billing {
        public String first_name;   //
        public String last_name;    //
        public String company;  //
        public String address_1;    //
        public String address_2;    //
        public String city; //
        public String state;    //
        public String postcode; //
        public String country;  //
        public String email;    //
        public String phone;    //
    }
    public class cls_shipping {
        public String first_name;   //
        public String last_name;    //
        public String company;  //
        public String address_1;    //
        public String address_2;    //
        public String city; //
        public String state;    //
        public String postcode; //
        public String country;  //
    }
    public class cls_date_paid {
    }
    public class cls_date_paid_gmt {
    }
    public class cls_date_completed {
    }
    public class cls_date_completed_gmt {
    }
    public class cls_meta_data {
    }
    public class cls_line_items {
    }
    public class cls_tax_lines {
    }
    public class cls_shipping_lines {
    }
    public class cls_fee_lines {
    }
    public class cls_coupon_lines {
    }
    public class cls_refunds {
    }
    public static MyJSON parse(String json){
        String jsonReplace =  json.replace('"currency":', '"currencyRep":');
               jsonReplace =  jsonReplace.replace('"number"','"numberRep"');
        return (MyJSON) System.JSON.deserializeStrict(json, MyJSON.class);
    }
}
```

Jsonstring

```
{"id":164,"parent_id":0,"number":"164","order_key":"wc_order_UeaNTHik3jec4","created_via":"admin","version":"3.5.7","status":"completed","currency":"EUR","date_created":"2019-03-22T08:37:18","date_created_gmt":"2019-03-22T08:37:18","date_modified":"2019-03-22T08:37:32","date_modified_gmt":"2019-03-22T08:37:32","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"0.00","total_tax":"0.00","prices_include_tax":false,"customer_id":0,"customer_ip_address":"","customer_user_agent":"","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"","email":"","phone":""},"shipping":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"payment_method":"","payment_method_title":"","transaction_id":"","date_paid":"2019-03-22","date_paid_gmt":"2019-03-22T08:37:32","date_completed":"2019-03-22T08:37:32","date_completed_gmt":"2019-03-22T08:37:32","cart_hash":"","meta_data":[],"line_items":[],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[]}
```

Comment: N.B. Consider the convention `currencyX` and `numberX` instead of `currencyRep`, and `numberRep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class passes the wrong string to `JSON.deserialize()`.

```
public static MyJSON parse(String json){
    String jsonReplace =  json.replace('"currency":', '"currencyRep":');
           jsonReplace =  jsonReplace.replace('"number"','"numberRep"');
    return (MyJSON) System.JSON.deserializeStrict(json, MyJSON.class);
```

You're transforming the string, but then not using the transformed version. Change the final line to

```
    return (MyJSON) System.JSON.deserializeStrict(jsonReplace, MyJSON.class);
```

Comment: Kicking myself right now for not seeing this.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks! I feel really bad for missing this one.